# What gradient boosting library is the easiest to implement on mobile?

Tags: random-forest, xgboost

I think of implementing training and predicting in an app (both Android and iOS), but existing packages I found not seem to be very mobile-friendly (scikit-learn, xgboost, lightgbm).

Random forest will also work fine.

Maybe you guys could advise an easier way so it does not require a lot of porting?

Would appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: Here is a BSD licensed RF in Java.  [link](https://github.com/ironmanMA/Random-Forest)